# Сборка jar файла с картинками

Tags: java, изображения, maven, jar, сборка

Как получить `jar` файла при помощи мавена? Есть приложение с простым `gui` на `swing`. В этом приложении есть `JLabel` в который я вставляю картинку.

Вот пример кода вставки картинки и частичная структура проекта:

```java
jLabelName.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src\\main\\resources\\images\\spritzExample.jpg"));
```

Скриншот:

[image: структура проекта в maven]

Проблема в том, что если делаю `jar` файл обычным способом, то картинки не подгружаются.

Код `pom` файла:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
              http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>name</groupId>
    <artifactId>name</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этих целей существует `maven-resources-plugin`. В настройках нужно указать расположение папки с ресурсами и в какую папку их копировать в архиве:

```xml
<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>resources</targetPath>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/properties</directory>
            <targetPath>properties</targetPath>
        </resource>
        . . .
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        . . .
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Затем получить ресурсы (если это картинки) можно так:

```java
BufferedImage[] images = new BufferedImage[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    images[i] = ImageIO.read(
            ThisClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/" + i + ".png"));
}
```

Comment: Все отлично работает, но есть одна проблема: Программа перестала видеть xml файл log4j2. Полагаю, что путь к нему как то надо явно указать. Если Вы знаете как это сделать, пожалуйста напишите. Спасибо за совет!

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем решил вопрос создав в корне проекта папку images и сделав там соответствующие картинки. В самом проекте пути к картинкам прописал так:

```
Obgect.setImages("images/imageName.jpg");
```

При сборки проекта в архив, вместе с jar файлом помещаю и папку с картинками. При распаковке всего архива в единую папку все файлы подгружаются нормально. На винде работает, мб на других ОС надо пользоваться спец инструментом для определения направления слэшей, но это не точно, не тестил)